# Vuejs/JavaScript and Outbound Transfer Behavior

Tags: data-transfer

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around outbound transfer as a project of mine makes it a concern.

I discovered that if I try to play music directly off of my server, it counts towards my outbound transfer. This is understandable and I can understand the logic of that.

The idea I have is if I happen to host the file elsewhere, would the outbound transfer be counted towards my initial server, my 3rd party server, or both? I'm considering putting the music on dropbox for example and stream it from there through the server.

Is what I want even possible?

Answer (score 1):

"outbound transfer" in this case most likely refers to the amount of bytes sent from that server. If you proxy the 3rd party server, you still send that data through your own server, so it won't net you any benefit, other than storage space. In fact, the latency will probably increase.

What you want to do is of course possible if you let the client connect directly to the streaming service. Just make sure that service allows you to stream data that way through their TOS. Also make sure that the service is actually designed for live streaming of data, or your user experience will be horrible.